# java read binary input as 49,48

Tags: java, maven, input, binary, byte

I am getting this input 10010011 00000001
with:

```
byte[] binaryInput = new byte[1024];
int bytesReadinput = System.in.read(binaryInput);

// Create a ByteArrayInputStream object for the binary input.
ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(binaryInput, 0, bytesReadinput);
```

why java get the input as 49,48,48,49,48,48,49,49,32,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,49

and how can I change it to the actual binary value? 0x93 0x01 ?

Comment: You have some fundamental problems of understanding (probably). Firstly, you need to state what *and how* you do your input. Bear in mind that 49 and 48 are the decimal ASCII values of 1 and 0. Each of your two binary strings takes *8 bytes* and *NOT bits*

Comment: so how can I read input as bits

Comment: Well you didn't answer my question, so I can't advise

Comment: i am getting this from file with a binary data

Comment: You mean a text file with ones and zeros? If so, how is it formatted

Comment: “I am getting this input 10010011 00000001” —Is that the output you are currently getting, or is that the output you want to get?

Comment: @VGR, afaics what is going on is the equivalent of `echo  '10010011 00000001' | java Main`. A file could be involved in providing that input

Comment: @g00se Ah, I see now. Noami wants to convert each sequence of eight ASCII binary digits to a byte value.

Answer (score -1):

You probably need something like this, based on your *i am getting this from file with a binary data*

```
    public static byte[] parseBitsFile(String path) throws IOException {
        String s = Files.readString(Path.of(path)).replaceAll("[^01]", "");
        byte[] result = new byte[s.length() / 8];
        StringReader sr = new StringReader(s);
        char[] byteVal = new char[8];
        int ix = 0;
        while(sr.read(byteVal) > -1) {
            result[ix++] = (byte)Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(byteVal), 2);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

The above assumes reading the whole file into memory is not a problem